# I want to mention group the user either admin or customer while register(programmatically) in Django. I am new to Django

Tags: python, django, web, web-development-server

[image]

From the **admin panel** I can group the **user** either **customer or admin**.
How do to **programmatically**?
This my function **register** in views.py.

```
@unauthenticated_user
def register(request):    
    form = CreateUserForm()    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            profile = form.save(commit=False) 
            profile.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            us1 =  User.objects.filter(username=user).first()
            us1.is_staff = True 
            us1.is_superuser = False 
            
            us1.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)
            return redirect('loginpage')
        

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

Comment: You can use `groups` field to add a user.

Answer (score 0):

`User` model has a field [**`groups`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.groups)):

> Many-to-many relationship to **[Group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Group)**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

my_group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
user.groups.add(my_group) 
# or
# my_group.user_set.add(user)
```